# How can we see objects with light being scattered in all directions from every object?

Tags: optics

Let's say you're looking at your keyboard on your phone.. let's take the letter g. Light from g is going in every direction.. we know this because we can see g from all angles above the phone. So light from g is also hitting your eye where you would see all the other keys,screen and background objects however we don't see g in those areas.. just wherever g is located. What happened to the images of g everywhere else but where we see it? We should be seeing g in all places but something happened and we don't.. if you're getting what I'm saying I you should be as perplexed as I am.. also knowing this now think about how a camera can take a picture with light from all objects being scattered in all directions.. it shouldn't be able to take a picture like it does.. how on earth was it even made???? It shouldn't be able to work but it does!!! Does this prove something else about life?

Comment: I don't have the time for a full answer, but the gist is: You are right, if our eyes were nothing but a light sensor (our retina), we would just see a washed up mixture of any light that can reach our eyes. But we have a lense in front of our light sensor which focuses light coming from a specific point (the letter g) onto a specific point of our sensor, so we have a sharp image. Same with a camera: If you remove the lens, so the sensor is exposed directly, you will get a washed up image. The lense in front focuses the light so that a sharp image is visible.

Answer (score -1):

Because light travels in straight lines and our eyes perceive objects based on that
For example light from stars bends continuosly before reaching our eyes, but our brain doesn't consider this fact and perceives the star a little above its position. Same is true for delayed sunset.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).